# Javascript textbox format for asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox, format

I am trying to use string format on client side

**Html:**

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="textbox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
```

If i use below code on code behind

**CodeBehind**

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", yourValue);
```

Above code works.

However i need to use **0:#,##0.00 format onkeypress textbox in client side**

What is **0:#,##0.00** in client side ?

How can i achieve this by using **javascript/jquery ?**